# Injecting angular element from controller but not working as directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My problem is that a html element needs to be replaced with a directive on event call. So i am calling a function in my controller on click event and appending the angular element at the desired position, that angular element is a directive so i need to do something to make it recognizable as directive. I have tried $compile but that doesn't work at controller level.

**My controller Code**

```
angular.element(document.body).append("<annotation></annotation> ");
```

**My Directive code**

```
app.directive("annotation", function($compile){

var linker = function(scope,element, attrs){
    element.html("Done "+attrs.content);

    if(attrs.content){

        $(element).tooltipster({
            content: $("<button class=\"btn btn-primary\">Highlight</button>"),
            animation: 'fade',
            delay: 200,
            interactive: true,
            theme: 'tooltipster-default',
            touchDevices: false,
            trigger: 'hover'
          });
    }

    $compile(element)(attrs);
}

return {
    restrict : "E",
    template: '<div class="highlightor"></div>',
    replace : true,
    link : linker,
    scope: {
        content: "="
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**: Something akin to this might work:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.onClick = function () {
        angular.element(document.body).append(
                $compile("<annotation></annotation>")($scope)
        );
    };
}]);
```

---

It *can* be made to work the way you want by injecting `$compile` into the *controller* and then doing DOM manipulation therein. However, it is not the correct approach and flouts one of the rules from [Zen of Angular](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1773).

> Do not do DOM manipulations in the Controller.

The Correct Way (TM), IMO, will be to have the click change a boolean flag on the `$scope` in the controller and then using that boolean flag to switch between the templates:

**Template:**

```
<div ng-if="!annotationVisible" ng-click="showAnnotation()">
    Click here to see annotations.
</div>
<div ng-if="annotationVisible"><annotation></annotation></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.annotationVisible = false;
$scope.showAnnotation = function () { $scope.annotationVisible = true; };
```

Comment: but i need this tag to be inserted at various positions wherever user defines the annotation.

Comment: so i can not declare this tag in html view as it is know after calling the api for annotations.

Comment: @user3351458 Updated the answer. Does that bring you a step closer to solving your problem?

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can u tell me how can i inject the compile inside my controller

Comment: @user3351458 We just did: `app.controller('myController', function ($compile) { ... })` will inject `$compile` into the controller.